# Failed to start Raise network interfaces while trying systemctl status networking.service in 16.04

Tags: networking, ssh, network-manager, aws

I need help to resolve this issue

I'm trying to connect to AWS ubuntu server via command  `ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/micro.pem ubuntu@ipaddress` it asks for `debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 530 Please login with USER and PASS` and exists.

Then I tried command `systemctl status networking.service` and `systemctl restart networking`. 
It shows Failed to start Raise network interfaces error

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Can anyone please help me resolve this

thank you

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu, when posting on this site you should avoid posing screenshots of the terminal where possible. Instead please copy and paste the text into the question using the formatting for large code blocks see [commonly-accepted-formatting-guidelines](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15446/lets-agree-on-some-commonly-accepted-formatting-guidelines) on the meta for details.